# Prove 1 is an adherent and accummulation point for $A=\{1+ \frac{1}{n}$ : n$\in$ $\mathbb N$\}

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $A=\{1+ \frac{1}{n}$ : n$\in$ $\mathbb N$}. Is $1$ an adherent point, an accummulation point or both for this set?
I think that $1$ is an adherent point because $B(1, r) \cap A \neq \emptyset$ for all $r>0$. But what about an accummulation point? 
Any tips? I don't need a formal proof, just the logic behind it.

Comment: **Note:** $x$ is an [adherent point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adherent_point) iff $x \in \overline{A}$.

Comment: Your title has accumulated too many 'm's :-).

Comment: @copper.hat these accumulation points are particularly delicious

Comment: oh, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Smartie...

Answer (score 1):

For any $\epsilon>0$, there is some $n$ such that ${1 \over n} < \epsilon$ and
so $1+{1 \over n} \in B(1,\epsilon)$. Since $1 \neq 1+{1 \over n}$, we
see that $1$ is both an accumulation point and an adherent point.

Every accumulation point is an adherent point.

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

By definition of an accumulation point, it suffices to note that no matter how small $r>0$ is, we'll never have $(B(1,r) \cap A) \setminus \{1\} = \emptyset$.  Since $1 \notin A$, it suffices to note that $B(1,r) \cap A$ is never empty.